# React.js - how to hit enter without creating an enter space (paragraph space)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, focus

When you hit enter a new filed will be created but the problem is the `focus` and the focus will move to the newly created filed, but the problem is : its leave `an enter space in the previous` field
`

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let elements = [
    { id: 0, text: "first", autoFocus: true },
    { id: 1, text: "second", autoFocus: true },
    { id: 2, text: "third", autoFocus: true }
  ];
  const [state, setstate] = useState(elements);
  function handChange(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const index = state.findIndex((item) => item.id == e.target.id);
      //i'm using autoFocus to move the focus  (I-beam pointer) to the nex field.
      //but i still get errors with it
      Object.assign(state, (state[index].autoFocus = false));

      setstate((pre) => {
        return [
          ...pre.slice(0, index + 1),
          { id: 3, text: "xxx", autoFocus: true },
          ...pre.slice(index + 1, state.length)
        ];
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById(index + 1).focus();
      }, 0);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map((e) => (
        <div contentEditable="true" id={e.id} onKeyUp={handChange}>
          {e.text}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-silence-c1t1k?file=/src/App.js:0-1092)

Answer (score 1):

The focus attribute will not work on a `div` element.

You should use an `input` element with the `autoFocus` attribute in React.

```
<input autoFocus={e.autoFocus} value={e.text} id={e.id} onKeyUp={handChange}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out to clone the state then map it by updating the `autoFocus` and `text` properties :

```
 function handChange(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      let _state = [...state];

      setstate(
        _state.map((item) => {
          if (+e.target.id === +item.id) {
            return {
              ...item,
              autoFocus: false
            };
          } else if (+e.target.id + 1 === +item.id + 1) {
            return {
              ...item,
              autoFocus: true,
              text: "xxx"
            };
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        })
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map((e) => (
        <input
          focus={e.autoFocus}
          contentEditable="true"
          id={e.id}
          onKeyUp={handChange}
          value={e.text}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I solved that using `        document.getElementById(index + 1).focus();` but it need to be wared by settimeout(,0)

Comment: it's not recommended to manipulate the DOM that way, your component should be data driven

Comment: You're using reactjs and you should respect its pattern

Comment: I respect your point but I'm programming for the sake of efficiency, not to worship frameworks